# Excel Index match: Reference workbook with wildcards?

Tags: excel

I have the following index match array formula:

```
=INDEX('[Copy of depot memo.xlsm]Sheet1'!$AX:$AX,MATCH(H22&I22,'[Copy of depot memo.xlsm]Sheet1'!$D:$D&'[Copy of depot memo.xlsm]Sheet1'!$J:$J,0))
```

I am trying to use wildcards for my workbook name.

My workbook can change name from time to time but will always have depot memo in it like so:

```
food depot memo.xlsm
drinks depot memo 123.xlsm
```

Please can someone show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that can be done. An external file needs an exact file name reference. By their very nature, wildcards may return more than one match. And yes, you will swear that there will ever only be one file that will match the wildcard, but Excel will still not accept wildcards in file names.

If the source file name needs to change, do this:

- Open the source file
- Open the file with the formulas
- use "Save As" to save the source file with the new name
- save and close the file with the formulas

Now you can swap out the data in the source file or overwrite it with another file of the same name and your formulas will not break.